# Striped Logical Volume

Tags: lvm

Im currently setting up a lab for LVM, three PV sdb1 sdc1 and sdd1. A striped logical volume is created named stripe01 with PV sdb1 and sdc1. Are there any options in lvconvert to add/remove a stripe to/from stripe01.